# Unable to send data from JavaScript to PHP file using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm unable to retrieve the `q` parameter sent from the PHP. 
When I run my code, null values get inserted in my database.

Here are the concerning parts of my code:

My JavaScript function:

```js
function load_now(str){
  //alert(str);
  var id = str.split("+")[0];
  var r = confirm("Start load process for scooter " + str + "?");
  if (r == true) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //console.log(str);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "load_scooter_action.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

and my load_scooter_action.php file:

```php
<?php
require "checkUserModel.php";
require "databaseController.php";
$databaseController = new DatabaseController();
$databaseController->startConnexionToDatabase();
$conn = $databaseController->getConn();

$dateObject = new DateTime();
$startTime  = $dateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user = $_SESSION['user-id'];

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
//forme:(scooter, lat, lng, chg);
$val = explode("+",$q);
$scooter = val[0];
$lat = val[1];
$lng = val[2];
$chg = val[3];

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> console.log(".$q.")</script>";

$sql = "UPDATE `scooters` SET `disponible` = '0' WHERE `scooters`.`numero` = '$scooter';";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $add = "\nScooter Taken";
} else {
  $add = "Error Taking scooter" . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "
    INSERT
    INTO Reloads(scooter, user, initialLoad, finalLoad, sourceX, sourceY,destinationX, destinationY, startTime,endTime)
    VALUES ('$scooter','$user','$chg',null,'$lat','$lng',null ,null, '$startTime', null)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  //echo "\nNew record created successfully";
  //echo '<script>window.location.href = "../php/scooterMapIndex.php";</script>';
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Could you help me have a clear understanding of my mistake?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
`str` is has the following form `599+50.8037+4.32782+4`

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors? Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I mistakenly forgot the `$` before `val`.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: **Watch out!** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. This web-app could be hacked very quickly. Sanitize your inputs; `$lat`, `$lng` and `$chg` are user-controllable and cannot be trusted. You are however simply concatenating them into your query string. Seriously, fix this ASAP, it is a critical security hole; complete database takeover could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes: 
The first one is a quick fix. Replace `val` with `$val`
The second one is that, although `str` is of the form `599+50.8037+4.32782+4` in the .js file, `$q` gets retrieved without the `+` characters in the .php file. Therefore it has to be split appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show me that what is passed in str or which value is passed in str load_now function. Do you get value when you alert(str)?

If yes then try below function

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'follow_user.php?user_id='.urlencode($user_id),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('done');
                }
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.

Comment: I think so we need clarification without that how can one reach to a conclusion.I am sorry but this is unfair

Comment: What you should have done is use a 'comment' rather than an 'answer.'

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)